# How to access class properties outside the constructor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to retrieve my other football attributes (crossing, dribbling, finishing, ball control) that haven't been requested as arguments in the constructor- reportID, playerID and comments are all that are required.

There are over 20 football attributes, so I've just included the first few for readability.

Report Class:

```
Public Class Report

Public Sub New(ByVal reportID As Integer, ByVal playerID As Integer, ByVal comments As String)

        _ReportID = reportID
        _PlayerID = playerID
        _Comments = comments

    End Sub

    Private _ReportID As Integer = 0
    Private _PlayerID As Integer = 0
    Private _Comments As String = ""

    Private _Crossing As Integer = 0
    Private _Dribbling As Integer = 0
    Private _Finishing As Integer = 0
    Private _BallControl As Integer = 0

Public Property ReportID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ReportID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _ReportID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PlayerID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _PlayerID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _PlayerID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Comments() As String
        Get
            Return _Comments
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Comments = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Crossing() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Crossing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Crossing = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Dribbling() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Dribbling
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Dribbling = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Finishing() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Finishing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Finishing = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BallControl() As Integer
        Get
            Return _BallControl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _BallControl = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Below I realise I'm only adding reportID, playerID and comments to my typeList, which is why I'm getting all 0's for my other attributes. How do access the attributes as well?

Retrieving the data:

```
Private Function retrieveReport() As List(Of Report)

        Dim typeList As New List(Of Report)
        Dim Str As String = "SELECT * FROM Report ORDER BY PlayerID"
        Try
            Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBConnection)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmdQuery As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Str, conn)
                    Using drResult As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader()
                        While drResult.Read
                            typeList.Add(New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("Comments")))
                        End While                   
                    End Using 'Automatically closes connection
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Report Exception: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & Str)
        End Try

        Return typeList
    End Function

    Private Sub setReport()

        For Each rpt As Report In retrieveReport()

            '*****General Information
            UC_Menu_Scout1.txtComments.Text = rpt.Comments

            '*****Technical
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXCrossing.Text = rpt.Crossing
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXDribbling.Text = rpt.Dribbling
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXFinishing.Text = rpt.Finishing
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXBallControl.Text = rpt.BallControl
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXPassing.Text = rpt.Passing
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXHeadingAccuracy.Text = rpt.HeadingAccuracy
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXMarking.Text = rpt.Marking
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXTackling.Text = rpt.Tackling
            '*****Mental
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXAggression.Text = rpt.Aggression
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXPositioning.Text = rpt.Positioning
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXAnticipation.Text = rpt.Anticipation
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXComposure.Text = rpt.Composure
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXVision.Text = rpt.Vision
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXTeamwork.Text = rpt.Teamwork
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXWorkRate.Text = rpt.WorkRate
            '*****Physical
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXPace.Text = rpt.Pace
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXBalance.Text = rpt.Balance
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXJumping.Text = rpt.Jumping
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXStrength.Text = rpt.Strength
            UC_Menu_Scout1.UcAttributes1.lblXStamina.Text = rpt.Stamina

        Next

    End Sub
```

I imagine it's not that hard, so any help would be appreciated please!

Comment: Attributes are something completely different from what you are talking about. You are referring to Properties and you can easily call them by dotting off the object. `myReport.Finishing = 1234`. It's no different than when you are setting the label `Text` property in your `setReport()`.

Comment: you can also get rid of *lots* of that code using auto properties: `Public Property Dribbling() As Integer` is all you need unless you need to qualify values in the setter or it is ReadOnly.  VS/VB will provide a "hidden" backing field you can still use (`_Dribbling`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add values to the properties, use `With`:

```
typeList.Add(New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("Comments")) With {.BallControl = drResult("BallControl"), .Dribbling = drResult("Dribbling")})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the property values that you aren't providing to the constructor as arguments, or you can add arguments to the constructor.  Try this -- instead of calling the constructor like this:

```
typeList.Add(New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("Comments")))
```

instead, do this:

```
dim rep = New Report(drResult("ReportID"), drResult("PlayerID"), drResult("Comments"))
    .Crossing = drResult("Crossing")
    'additional property assignments
With rep

End With

typeList.Add(rep)
```